# Comparing a date from the picker to current date

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my date picker i can select a date from the list.

I save it in my string pickUpDateTime

```
 self.pickUpDateTime = [NSString stringWithString:[apiFormat stringFromDate:d]];
```

I'm having a problem where the user is able to pick a date in the past. Is there some way to get the current day and check that its in the future?

My string holds the date like this 2010-11-04.
The user shouldnt be able to select a day in the past or the current day.

Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current date and time with:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
```

Compare the 2 dates with:

```
if ([d compare:now] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    // d is later than now
} else {
    // d is earlier than or equal to now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `UIDatePicker`, just set

```
datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:24*3600];
```

e.g. to allow dates starting tomorrow. Working back from the date string "2010-11-04" to a `NSDate` object is possible but cumbersome. (but if you insist, have a look at `NSDateFormatter`)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers above give good advice about working with NSDates in general; things are a tiny bit more complicated if you want to round to the start of the day to say e.g. 'at least tomorrow' rather than 'at least 24 hours away'.

In general terms:

1. get an instance of NSCalendar to represent the Gregorian calendar
2. use the NSCalendar to convert an NSDate into an NSDateComponents representing just the day, month and year
3. use the NSCalendar to convert the NSDateComponents back into an NSDate
4. use arithmetic as recommended elsewhere to increment the NSDate a day into the future, for example

I have to dash, but relevant methods are:

- NSCalendar +currentCalendar or -initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar to be extra safe
- NSCalendar -components:fromDate: (the first parameter is a flag field indicating which bits of the date you need to be filled in) and -dateFromComponents:
- NSDate -timeIntervalSinceDate:

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

   NSString *tempStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];

    txtBirth.text=tempStr;

    NSString *birthDate = tempStr;   
    NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];

    int time = [todayDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[df dateFromString:birthDate]];

    int numberOfDays = time/86400;
```

hear number of data return data difference.....